# Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'app-button'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have modal components built with ngx-bootstrap and `<app-button>` components from myself.
I created a `modal.module.ts` file to declare all the modal components to the app. The `ButtonComponent` is declared in my `app.module.ts` file to be available everywhere.

modal.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

import { KeyboardComponent } from '../keyboard/keyboard.component';
import { AlertModalComponent } from './alert-modal/alert-modal.component';
import { ConfirmModalComponent } from './confirm-modal/confirm-modal.component';
import { LanguageModalComponent } from './language-modal/language-modal.component';
import { KeyboardModalComponent } from './keyboard-modal/keyboard-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AlertModalComponent,
    ConfirmModalComponent,
    LanguageModalComponent,
    KeyboardModalComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    KeyboardComponent,
    AlertModalComponent,
    ConfirmModalComponent,
    LanguageModalComponent,
    KeyboardModalComponent
  ]
})
export class ModalModule {

  constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {
    modalService.config.backdrop = false;
    modalService.config.ignoreBackdropClick = true;
  }

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { ModalModule } from './components/modal/modal.module';

...

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ButtonComponent } from './components/button/button.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ButtonComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ModalModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

button.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent {

  @Input() icon: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() label: string;

}
```

alert-modal.component.html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p [innerHTML]="message"></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <app-button [icon]="'validate'" [color]="'red'" [label]="'OK'" (tap)="validate()"></app-button>
</div>
```

However, I have an error at runtime:

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'app-button'.
1. If 'app-button' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <app-button [ERROR ->][icon]="'validate'" [color]="'red'" [label]="'OK'" (tap)="validate()"></app-button>
</div>
"): ng:///ModalModule/AlertModalComponent.html@4:18
```

The `icon` property is well defined as a property of a `<app-button>` so I don't see this error as a legit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mentions a `vesta-button`, but I don't see that declared anywhere. It looks like you may have declared a `vesta-button` tag in your markup instead of `app-button`, in which case you'll need to update the markup to say `app-button` instead.

**EDIT**

In this case, it looks like you're trying to use `app-button` (`ButtonComponent`) within the `ModalModule`. However, that isn't going to work, because `ModalModule` can't import `AppModule`. Instead, you'll need to create a `SharedModule` that contains your `ButtonComponent`, then import that into `ModalModule`:

**shared.module.ts**

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  exports: [ButtonComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

Then move `ButtonComponent` into the `Shared` module folder.

**modal.module.ts**

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class ModalModule {
  ...
}
```

You can also import `SharedModule` in `AppModule` so you can use the button there as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
If 'app-button' is an Angular component
```

This message means that the Angular compiler does not recognize the XML name `app-button` as a *selector* for a component.

The error is being generated when the `ModalModule` is being compiled, because that module does not *import* another module that exports this component or it does not directly declare the component itself.

Look at your code, the `ButtonComponent` is declared in the `AppModule`, but that module imports `ModalModule`.

You need to move `ButtonComponent` to another module (maybe named it `ButtonModule`) and ensure that it is *exported*, then you can *import* that module into `ModalModule`.

Generally, it's a bad practice to add components to your `AppModule`. You should create *sharable* modules that contain your components to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: OK, I moved all the components from app.module.ts to their own module.